# springframework get all request headers

Tags: java, servlets, spring-mvc

I know that spring3 has `@RequestHeader` to get a single request header in a controller. I'm wondering if there is an easy way to get ALL the request headers? I'm hoping for something like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/some/url",RequestMethod.GET)
public void endpoint(RequestParams params, BindingResult result, @RequestHeader MultiValueMap<String,String> headers, HttpServletRequest request, ModelMap model) {

}
```

Currently I'm doing something like this:

```
MultiValueMap<String,String> headers = new HttpHeaders();
for (Enumeration names = request.getHeaderNames(); names.hasMoreElements();) {
    String name = (String)names.nextElement();
    for (Enumeration values = request.getHeaders(name); values.hasMoreElements();) {
        String value = (String)values.nextElement();
        headers.add(name,value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 51, accepted):

From the Javadocs:

> @RequestHeader can be used on a Map, MultiValueMap, or HttpHeaders method parameter to gain access to all request headers.

More info is available online [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html) and [there](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.8.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/method/annotation/RequestHeaderMapMethodArgumentResolver.html).

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to read doc:

```
mappingMethodName(@RequestHeader Map<String, String> headers) {
    headers.forEach((key, value) -> {
        System.out.printf("Header '%s' = %s%n", key, value);
    });
}
```